# Why does the # mean beside trained units in SC2?

Tags: starcraft-2

In starcraft 2 there is a building that allows you to buy trained units and there is a cooldown on them. What does the # beside it mean and what happens when you get to 0? Does the # reset every map?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you're talking about the Mercenary building. As you surmised, the # displayed indicates how many more times you can hire that band of mercs.

It resets every map.

Comment: I got nervous and thought i need to hire them again (full price, and no reset)